# Why isn't gettext parameterized?

Tags: internationalization, translate, gettext

Currently:

- translators are exposed to programming language detail
- text is programming language specific (%s)
- translators cannot change ordering of strings (for example: family name comes first in hungarian)

`printf(gettext("My name is %s %s."), first, family);`

`msgid "My name is %s %s."`

`msgstr "A nevem %s %s."`

Why not like this:

`printf(gettext("My name is Peter Smith.",[("Peter",first),("Smith",family)]));`

`msgid "My name is Peter Smith." with "Peter","Smith"`

`msgstr "A nevem Smith Peter."`

GUI can highlight that `Smith` and `Peter` are parameter-names and check their presence. One could use `givenname` and `familyname` instead.

Would this have much worse performance? Any other issue I overlooked?

Comment: Am I getting the downvotes because of the bad example? There are less silly examples where strings have to be reordered when translating.

Comment: I assume it's because asking "Why did X (not) do Y?" is *usually* an opinion poll whose answers are speculative at best. I was unsure about this particular question myself, so I haven't voted on it either way, but it seemed to get a good answer regardless.

Comment: it is worth taking away that this seemingly opinion-asking question got an answer for which it was worth asking so one should not be hasty with judging

Comment: To be fair, the answer is good because it completely dodges the actual question (it has no explanation for why gettext() uses %s instead of %1, %2, etc) in favor of arguing that the question isn't that important. So I'm not sure that this implies anything about the validity of our collective voting behavior. I still can't think of a non-speculative question this could be safely edited into, so I can't really blame the downvoters for downvoting instead of editing. Might be a good topic for meta or chat discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proper localization is incredibly difficult. E.g. many languages feature complicated rules for declension that might change the root of the word, or depends on the grammatical gender of that word in the target language. My primary language is German, where articles are gendered. So a template `"I'm holding a %s"` would need to have three different German forms:

- `"Ich halte eine %s"` for feminine words such as *Blume* (flower).
- `"Ich halte einen %s"` for masculine words such as *Schlüssel* (key).
- `"Ich halte ein %s"` for neutral words such as *Band* (ribbon).

In fact, the English indefinite article `a/an` depends on the starting sound of the following word, so even this case is difficult to represent in a localization system without a complicated rule engine.
Even within the indo-germanic group of languages (which share common grammatical features), there are unique cases that make it impossible to have a simple substitution-based translation tool.

So, can we have an ideal translation tool? Yes, by using a proper programming language rather than a substitution-based system. In such an architecture, we would associate each message key with a callback that is responsible for returning a properly localized string with equivalent meaning, depending on the context information passed into that callback. Unfortunately, this requires the translators to be programmers, and the language to have decent support for callbacks. Switching the language is not as simple as reading from a different translation file, instead it probably requires us to dynamically link to another library.

All of this complication is a good argument for not using perfect solutions, and rather doing something that works sufficiently well in most cases, especially when this translation engine has to work within the restrictions of C. If gettext were parameterized and included a complex template engine – it would still struggle to properly portray the whole wealth of human languages.

---

Names are a whole chapter of their own on difficulties of localization – partially because quite a lot cultures place the “family name” before the “given name”, but mostly because many people don't have exactly two names that fit exactly these two roles. [40 Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) is an entertaining read on this topic. In the context of software systems, it would be best to stop distinguishing first and family names except as needed for legal reasons, and rather use a display name that contains the full name in any order or formatting that person prefers. Note that the correct name order depends on the person carrying that name, not on the context in which that name is being displayed in.

Comment: I only used the name example because I started from the wikipedia article and wanted a second argument.

Comment: The obvious way to handle your German example is "Ich halte %s" where the fill in string is *eine blume*, *einen schlussel*, or *ein band*.  However, I understand your point where other words in the sentence may have to change as well.

Comment: to sum up: perfect is impractical anyway, might aswell use sufficient and trivial solution

Comment: @wallyk for example adjectives in spanish match gender of noun

Comment: @amon I think a 1st order functional language would be enough e.g. german "I hold a/an x" = "Ich halte conjugate("ein",gender(german(x))) german(x)"; but I still agree that "sufficient and simple" is better